# How to Client Socket auto connect with available Server socket, over wifi network

Tags: android

Hi I am working with android Socket programming. Now I am entering the Server IP manually from Client UI. My query, is any way to get available Server IP programmatically like xcender join group. Is possible post your sample codes.

Comment: Is your android device is client or server? Is there any dependency are you using for socket programming?

Comment: Inside my application I am using Server and Client module.

Comment: Your query is to get available Server IP programmatically. One option is that connect to local host with specific port number from your client side like `http://localhost:38500`. Change in your server to listen same in localhost with 38500 port number. So in this case multiple client can connect like xcender as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The client can determine its own ip. And knows that the ip of the server is about the same. Only the last group of digits will differ.

So make a loop and let a Socket try to connect to ip's 'around' its own ip. Set a small connection timeout.

Within seconds the server will be found.